# How can I simplify function application with (->) r Monad or which other (->) r type class instance may be useful here?

Tags: haskell, monads

For example I have following code:

```
func1 :: a -> b
func3 :: b -> b -> b -> c

myExample x y z = func3 (func1 x) (func1 y) (func1 z)
```

Any general suggestion for this case?

Comment: That doesn't seem to be a case for the `(->) r` Monad instance. The `(->) r` Monad instance is for providing a "supply of `r`" to (multiple) functions. Instead, you have the same function and a bunch of different `r`'s.

Comment: If you really wanted to use `(->) r` you could write `myExample x y z = (func3 <$> ($ x) <*> ($ y) <*> ($ z)) func1`. But I have to agree it's not really a sensible use.

Comment: Is there any way to just DRY here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `(->) r` monad don't really "simplify application."  The simplest way of applying a function is just to apply the function!

I find the most intuitive way of getting a feel for `(->) r` is that it allows you to **operate on the result types of functions that share the same argument type**.  Say for example you have these functions:

```
f :: a -> b -> c
g :: r -> a
h :: r -> b
```

In this case, observe that:

1. `f` operates on the result types of `g` and `h`.
2. `g` and `h` share the same argument type.

Now using the `Applicative` instance (superclass of `Monad`) for `(->) r`, you can write this:

```
import Control.Applicative (liftA2)

example :: r -> c
example = liftA2 f g h
```

So if you have many functions that all take a shared "context" argument of type `r`, and your code is threading it around everywhere, you can sometimes simplify your code by using the `Reader r` monad (which is just a `newtype` around `(->) r`) to write code that "pretends" the context value has already been supplied.

---

Expanding on my first comment to this answer, given what you've told us about your example so far I don't see a case for using any of this machinery.  In this definition:

```
myExample x y z = func3 (func1 x) (func1 y) (func1 z)
```

...`func1` is applied to three different values, so the following would not be equivalent:

```
notYourExample = liftA3 func3 func1 func1 func1
```

That would be equivalent to this instead:

```
notYourExample x = func3 (func1 x) (func1 x) (func1 x)
```

The thing that is repeated in your function is not the arguments to `func1`, but rather `func1` itself.  You could use the `(->) r` monad to eliminate that repetition by applying some code golf:

```
myExample x y z = liftA3 func3 ($x) ($y) ($z) func1
```

Do you find that hard to read than the original?  Well, that's the reason not to do it!  It's might also not be strictly equivalent to your example, depending on the precise type of `func1`.

Comment: So for this example I should use liftA3 or liftM3, right?

Comment: @Netsu: The thing with `func3 (func1 x) (func1 y) (func1 z)` is that `func1` is applied to three different values, `x`, `y` and `z`. The `(->) r` monad works in cases where all the functions are fed *the same* value.

Comment: There should be a general way, like Data.Function.on function for 2 arguments, but for 3 in this case.

Answer (score 3):

The `(->) r` instance of Monad can be thought of as providing a "supply of `r`" to (multiple) functions. An example of its use might be:

```
example f g h x = f (g x) (h x)
```

which would become

```
example' f g h = do
  x1 <- g
  x2 <- h
  return (f x1 x2)
```

where the argument (originally `x`) is supplied to each function.

Your example doesn't have a single supply of `r` for multiple functions, but rather multiple `r` values for a single function. This is not a use case for the `(->) r` instance of Monad.